# asyncore socket doesn't close properly

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I've written (mostly copied) a very simple python script to function as a Caller ID addon for xbmc.  It works as expected except for closing the socket. I've confirmed that xbmc.abortRequested (a notification that XBMC is shutting down) does get set as True so the loop should end. But it doesn't (it seems to hang) and xbmc kills the script after about 5 seconds during its clean up. This ungraceful exit doesn't cause any problems but I'd prefer the script to exit properly. I can't figure out if there's some sort of other timeout that I can set or what.  Thanks for any help.

Doug

My code:

```
import socket, threading, thread, sys, asyncore, xbmc, xbmcgui, xbmcaddon
from time import *
from string import *

xbmc.log("YAC Listener: Starting")
PORT = 10629

class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(1)

    def handle_accept(self):
        socket, address = self.accept()
        ConnectionHandler(socket)

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()
        xbmc.log("YAC Listener: Closing Port")

class ConnectionHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def handle_read(self):
        self.buffer = self.recv(1024)
        self.buffer = split(self.buffer[5:], "~")
        self.close()
        global data
        if len(self.buffer) > 1:
            name = self.buffer[0]
            number = self.buffer[1]
                xbmc.executebuiltin("XBMC.Notification("+name+","+number+",7000,special://home/addons/script.yaclistener/phone.png)")
        else:
            data = self.buffer

s = Server('', PORT)

while not xbmc.abortRequested:
    asyncore.loop(timeout=1)

s.close()
sys.exit()
xbmc.log("YAC Listener: Exiting")
```

Answer (score 1):

"timeout" has a slightly different meaning (roughly can be considered as a loop granularity).

So the end-file code should be like smth like below:

```
...
while not xbmc.abortRequested:
    asyncore.loop(timeout=1, count=1)

# this will try to close ALL current connections:
asyncore.close_all()
# this will give some time (up to 5 seconds) for things to settle down:
asyncore.loop(timeout=1, count=5)
sys.exit()
xbmc.log("YAC Listener: Exiting")
```